# Openlayers 3: Draw Polygon (convex hull) around a cluster of points

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-2, convex-hull

I'm grouping a set of points as a cluster. Then I'm trying to draw a polygon around the points.

Please see this link: [Draw Poly](http://jsfiddle.net/NaghaveerGowda/mgk4179z/5/)

I tried by sorting the points based on co-ordinates. But still I'm not able to draw the polygon correctly.

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: vectorSource
      })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-16, 75],
    zoom:2
  })
});

//clusters
var min=1;
var max=20
for (j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
var polyCoords = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    var x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    var y = Math.random() * (max*2 - min*2) + min;  
  polyCoords.push( ol.proj.transform([-x,y],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));

  var point = new ol.geom.Point([-x, y]).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  var fea = new ol.Feature({geometry:point});
  vectorSource.addFeature(fea);
}

var thing = new ol.geom.Polygon( [polyCoords]);
var featurething = new ol.Feature({
    name: "Thing",
    geometry: thing
});
vectorSource.addFeature( featurething );
min=max+1;
max=max*2;
}
```

How can I draw a polygon around all the points?

Comment: So you want to draw a convex hull around your points, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hicham Zouarhi pointed out you want to create the **convex hull** from your `polyCoords`.
You can find an implementation of the [Graham Scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) Convex Hull algorithm for JavaScript on [github](https://github.com/brian3kb/graham_scan_js) (MIT License).
As describes the usage is simple:

```
//Create a new instance of ConvexHullGrahamScan.
var convexHull = new ConvexHullGrahamScan();

//add points using for loop on your coordinates
for (var i = 0; i < polyCoords.length ; i++) {
    // add your coordinates
    convexHull.addPoint(polyCoords[i][0], polyCoords[i][1]); 
}

// get point array from convex hull
var hullPoints = convexHull.getHull();

// create ol.geom.Polygon from hullPoints...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is with Turf.js, using `turf.convex` which takes a featureCollection of points and returns a feature polygon.
all this is done in Geojson format

```
var yourPolygon= turf.convex(yourPoints);
```

[Here](http://turfjs.org/docs/#convex) is a little description of it